# Unable to install GRUB message (Hera)

Tags: release-hera, grub, install

I was running Elementary OS Loki or Juno (don't remember) on my Asus T100TA laptop. I figured I'd do a clean install of Hera, and since I had nothing of value on my computer I just removed all partitions before proceeding (last resort after hours). I booted into the ISO and started installing (used the first option in the installer, no manual tinkering), but at the end I got the message: "Executing 'grub-install [...]' failed. This is a fatal error." I have tried both running the installer from within the OS, as well as installing it just after the dialog loads at the beginning. I've also connected my computer to the network and chosen to download updates, etc while installing. What do I do now?

---

No one who can help? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Create manually / partition, /home partition, /boot partition and swap partition and then try to install it. Swap format as swap, / and /home as ext4 and /boot as fat32 and set boot flag on this partition.

Comment: I have tried; it didn't work. I got the same GRUB error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install from the UEFI partition on your eOS USB stick. Just choose UEFI USB in the boot options menu when you start your computer.

Comment: There is no such option. The computer only uses UEFI as far as I know.

Comment: To be sure what your computer chooses, you need to enter the boot options menu by pressing an F-key at start up. It could be F2, F12 or F11 or even the Esc-key.

Comment: If you still don't see the UEFI option, you'll need to create your bootable eOS USB differently; with a partition scheme supported for UEFI.

Comment: [I think this link will help for your computer and creating a working bootable USB](https://superuser.com/a/1299725)

Comment: And [this link](http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/) maybe too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to boot to USB and NOT UEFI from boot option menu. Leave the internal hard disks as first bootable options in BIOS, use F-Key (usually F12) at bootup to enter boot option menu.

Then do manual partitioning.

Remove all partitions.

Create primary partition 512 - 1024 MB , format as fat32 and mount as /boot/EFI

Then create swap 8-16GB and format as swap and mount it as a swap.

Create a main partition as primary and here you can choose to format is as LVM, or ext4 and mount as / and give it 50% of your hard drive’s size.

LVM gives you later option to dynamically change the size of each LVM partitions.

Create extended or primary partition , format as LVM or ext4 and mount as /home and give it the second  50% of the hard drive’s size.

The grub boot loader fails during installation because the installation USB is still plugged in and the system is attempting to load the grub to the USB drive. Unplug the USB drive at the point in the installation when asked to install the grub boot loader.

Comment: I am never asked about installing GRUB; That happens automatically (too quickly for me to time with unplugging the usb). Then, how do I do the last part in practice?

Comment: Remove it earlier when it will start installing packages.

Comment: Doesn't work. It just crashes the installation.

Comment: Did you create /boot/EFI partition?

Comment: Yes, I created the /boot/EFI partition. Taking the usb stick out crashes the installation, no matter when I do it.

Comment: Ok. Can you download Elementary ISO file once again and prepare usb stick with balena etcher? Do not connect to the Internet. You will install updates later, after the installation.

Comment: I tried this now. I've been getting a warning message of missing efi partition after using your instructions, but I went ahead with it once again, and this time without internet. The installation finished without errors, but it won't boot, so clearly something wrong with the efi. Also tried creating it by selecting it in the menu in the installer instead where I'm making the partitions, and then I didn't get the warnings before proceeding. However, that gave me errors during the installation. So, basically this didn't work either.

Comment: So we moved step further. There are two options: you can make partitions manually as I mentioned and create /boot/EFI partition manually, format it as FAT32 and set boot flag on it during installation, or remove all partitions in manual mode, then go back and use guided partition installer, if it will not work just make one partition and make again guided partitioning and select this one partition as a partition for Elementary. The /boot/EFI partition is a must have if you need to run it with Secure Boot. Eventually you can disable Secure Boot in BIOS and try to install it once again.

Comment: There is no option to set a boot flag on any partition in manual mode. Edit: Have always had secure boot disabled.

Comment: Try to enable secure boot in bios, remove all partitions, make one ext partition, go back to the previous step , choose guided partitioning , select the partition you created and let it install for you.

Comment: What do you mean with guided partitioning. Where do you find that option? My options are either to "Erase disk and install Elementary" (gives me no option over which partitions to use, only disk) or "Something else" (which I've been doing all along).

Comment: Installer seemed to have done the right thing. It made a fat32 efi partition. However, it gave the message: "The'grub-efi-ia32' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot." at the end. And sure enough, it didn't boot afterwards. Enabling Secure Boot didn't change anything at this point either.

Comment: Turn on the internet and select to download updates while installing Elementary OS. It looks like the The'grub-efi-ia32' package is not on the installation iso image.
If this will not work try below:
Try to disable BIOS QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT).
And change setting in the BIOS `Boot tab➝UEFI/BIOS boot mode´ to legacy.

Comment: I have always connected to internet and downloaded updates under installation until you asked me to try not doing it. I will get the original GRUB error back if I update during installation, but that's because it's downloading it, I suppose. The BIOS does not have any QuickBoot/FastBoot or SRT, and there is no option to change  boot mode to legacy. It's an extremely basic bios (there hasn't been any updates; I have checked).  So, unfortunately this will not solve it.

Comment: What if you will create a system partition format as ext4 and mount as / , create home partition format as ext4 and mount as /home , create boot partition format as ext4 and mount as /boot and create swap partition format as swap ?

Comment: Bear in mind that this time it is a /boot not /boot/EFI